# Header is repeating when merging multiple files using Python shell in AWS Glue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am new to Python and AWS Glue.

I am trying to merge few excel files in a S3 source bucket and generate 1 output file (csv) in a target S3 bucket. I am able to read and generate the output file with merged data but the only problem is that the header is repeating from each file.

Can someone help to debug to remove the repeating headers?

**Below is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xlrd
import openpyxl
import boto3
import io
import json
import os
from io import StringIO 
import numpy as np

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('test bucket')
prefix_objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='source/file')
prefix_df = []
for obj in prefix_objs:
key = obj.key
print(key)
temp = pd.read_excel(obj.get()['Body'], encoding='utf8')
prefix_df.append(temp)

bucket = 'test bucket'
csv_buffer = StringIO()
for current_df in prefix_df:
current_df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index = None)
print(current_df)

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket, 'merge.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

Please help!

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and add the parameter `header`.

```
temp = pd.read_excel(obj.get()['Body'], encoding='utf8')
```

to

```
temp = pd.read_excel(obj.get()['Body'], encoding='utf8', header=1)
```

or

```
temp = pd.read_excel(obj.get()['Body'], encoding='utf8', skiprows=1)
```

You need to test the header value, because sometimes the header starts not in the first row.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: I have added some other option... in the documentation as more things that might help you